# When running 'npm start', npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600 comes up, in windows 8.1

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I was working on a blog project developed in Node, but I started having this problem out of nowhere. Whenever I try to 'npm start', this ERR! comes up, I already tried uninstalling and installing both node and npm, also tried to clean npm cache, and 'config set proxy AND registry', can't make it work. This is what I'm getting:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Nicolas\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.9.2
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! nodeblog@1.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the nodeblog@1.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the nodeblog package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs nodeblog
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls nodeblog
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Nicolas\Desktop\nodeBlog\nodeblog\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: WHAT is this?  Please refer to: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before responding or posting again. And make the proper effort to complete the 2-minute site tour as well.